# Connecting Anet 8 2004 display with Ramps 1.4 to Aux2 can't seem to figure it out

Tags: ramps-1.4, anet-a8

I've heard about switching out some connectors, but can't seem to figure out which ones and can't seem to find a diagram out there that is much help. Does anyone know which connectors I should switch to achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](/a/6044) clearly describes that you need to switch pins 1 and 2. It also describes that the MKS board is similar to a RAMPS board.

First thing to look for is the layout of the AUX2 header:

[image: Aux2 header pin layout ramps]

The pin layout reveals that pin 1 is VCC and pin 2 is GND. These need to be switched to be able to connect the display on AUX2.